# update_attributes, and then check if one of the attributes has changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Course model that users can edit and update using a form. In the controller, the update method calls `update_attributes(course_params)`, i.e. strong parameters. This is all standard and is working fine.

Now I'm trying to find out if a specific attribute is changing during the update. In particular, if the course object's `points` attribute is being changed by the user, I also need to mark the object's `points_recently_changed` attribute to true. The quick-and-dirty implementation would be like this:

```
def update
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  @old_points = @course.points
  @course.update_attributes(course_params)
  @new_points = @course.points
  if @old_points != @new_points
    @course.points_recently_changed = true
    @course.save
  end
end
```

A slightly less terrible way of doing it could be:

```
def update
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  @course.points_recently_changed = true if @course.points != params[:course][:points]
  @course.update_attributes(course_params)
end
```

However, neither of these satisfy my desire for a clean, efficient, and easy-to-read implementation. Ideally, update_attributes would optionally return an array of attributes that have actually changed during the update. But it doesn't.

I looked at [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), but the problem with that is it only works before save. And since I'm using update_attributes, which updates *and* saves, methods such as `has_changed?` would not work in my scenario.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. :)

**EDIT:**

Here's the form through which admins can update the course object:

```
<%= form_for(@course) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, required: true %>

  <%= f.label :course_logo %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :course_logo %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description, required: true %>

  <%= f.label :worth, "Points" %>
  <%= f.number_field :worth %>

  <%= f.label :tag_ids, "Tags" %>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_ids, data: { load: @course.tags } %>

  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.cktext_area(:content, rows: 10) %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: so... my immediate question is - what is it that changes points inside of the course? Can you show us that code?

Comment: It's a pretty standard form. I'll update the question - one second...

Comment: I'm wondering more if there is a method of after_X hook or similar that is the method that changes the points on the course... and doesn't save them..,. and perhaps that method could be updated to actually save them too.

Comment: it's not the form that I want... it's the method that changes the course-points while you'd doing an update_attributes... it is probably to be found inside your course model.

Comment: I currently don't have a specific method that changes just the course points. I do all such changes through update_attributes. The course's points is passed as part of course_params hash.

Comment: Right, ok, I had my head in a different space. So what you want is to only change all params if the points in the form is different to the points on the current course.

Comment: What you want is kind of unusual... I'd suggest that your second option does make it clear to later developers what you're doing and why - even if it isn't tucked away inside the model :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `after_validation` callback to update `points_recently_changed` attribute.

```
#course.rb

after_validation :points_changed, if: ->(obj){ obj.points.present? and obj.points_changed? }

def points_changed
  self.points_recently_changed = true
end
```

Explanation :

considering  `points` is a attribute in your `Course` model `points_changed?` method will return true or false based on whether the points attribute is updated or not .

An example

```
deep@IdeaPad:~/test/test_app$ rails c
2.1.1 :001 > course = Course.find(1)
=> #<Course id: 1, name: "Ruby on Rails", points: 2, points_recently_changed: true, created_at: "2014-06-16 01:51:48", updated_at: "2014-06-16 01:58:07"> 
2.1.1 :002 > course.changed? # will return true of false based on whether the course object has been updated or not
=> false 
2.1.1 :003 > course.points = "11"
=> "11"
2.1.1 :004 > course.points_changed?
=> true 
2.1.1 :005 > course.points_change
=> [2, 11]
```

Reference - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty

Note: You have to use `changed?` method before saving the record. Once the record is saved calling `changed?` will return false

Comment: Why write `p_changed?` at all when you can just do `obj.points_changed?`?

Comment: @enragedcamel ActiveRecord provides it. See the linked reference in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A faster and not (too) ugly method might be rewriting the update_attributes. This way you can check in the controller for

```
if @courses.changes
```

Solution in your courses controller:

```
  def update_attributes(attributes)
    self.attributes = attributes
    changes = self.changes
    save
    self.changes = changes
  end
```